# Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 installers can't detect nvme in raid mode

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, raid

I have an Asus G701-vo notebook. It comes with two 512 Samsung SSDs configure in RAID0 mode. Bios options allow only RAID configurations (no AHCI). The laptop comes with Windows 10, but I'd like to remove it and install Ubuntu.
The problem is Ubuntu installer can't detect my SSDs. I've been looking for a solution for about two weeks with no luck.
Any one had a similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a known problem with Linux. ATM, there is no driver for SSD RAID, unfortunately.

See this article: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/lenovo-denies-deliberately-blocking-linux-on-windows-10-pcs/

Hopefully, at some point, there will be a driver. *To any future viewers: if a driver becomes available, please leave a comment below.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not limited to Ubuntu, but it's due to the lack of support in the kernel.

You can try to completely disable `RAID` mode, if the system allows you to do so. In that case, Ubuntu will clearly see two different drives, but than can be solved by setting up a [software RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html) or setting up LVM with [striped logical volumes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StripedVolumeHowTo).

Comment: Unfortunately, *Bios options allow only RAID configurations (no AHCI)*, posted by the OP and many others. Also there are many other notebooks with the same problem.